# Why is beat described as a "relatively slow amplitude-modulation of oscillation"?

Tags: waves

Excerpts from A.P.French's **Vibrations & Waves**:

> . . . It may be seen that the combined displacement can be fitted within an envelope defined by the pair of equations$$ x = 2\mathit{A} \cos\dfrac{(\omega_1 - \omega_2).t}{2} \cdots (2-6)$$ because the **rapidly oscillating factor** i.e. $\mathit{A} = \cos \dfrac{(\omega_1 + \omega_2)t}{2}$ always lies between $[-1,+1]$ , & the Eq. $(2-6)$ describes a relatively **slow amplitude-modulation of the oscillation**. One will see that the time between **successive zeros of the modulating disturbance** is *one-half* the **period of the modulating factor**.

Now, that word **modulation** has maddened me! Though I know its meaning in english language, I evidently can't getting what the author wanted to tell by the bolded phrases.  Plz help me explaining these intuitively.

[N.B. I am not an expert; just have started wave-mechanics. So, . . . :)]

Comment: Have I asked a wrong question here? Do downvote generously but please post a comment before or after doing so . . .

Comment: . . .writting a comment doesn't bother the time. I am a student; don't know everything . So, I'm here. Downvoting without any plea is a great slap on my face.

Comment: I suspect the downvoter thinks you should have Googled [*amplitude modulation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation). I suppose I basically agree, though of course Googling is always easier when you already know what you're Googling for. Anyhow have an upvote from me to cancel the downvote :-)

Comment: @John Rennie: Thanks, sir; actually I did google it but it was a horrendous experience after I read the wiki article ; so intricate.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In order for the occurence of beat, why is it compulsory that $|{\omega_2 - \omega_1}| \ll \omega_1 + \omega_2$?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161601/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *modulation* as used here means [amplitude modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation).

If you have some wave with a high frequency, call this $f(t)$, then you can multiply it by another signal with a much lower frequency, call this $g(t)$. The effect of $g$ is basically to modulate the intensity of $f$ up and down as a function of time.

In this case when you sum your two waves with frequencies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ you get a wave $f(t)$ with a frequency $(\omega_1 + \omega_2)/2$, multiplied by a wave $g(t)$ with frequency $(\omega_1 - \omega_2)/2$. So the signal you observe is the product $g(t)f(t)$. If $\omega_1 \approx \omega_2$, which it is in this case, then $f$ is high frequency and $g$ is low frequency. So $g$ modulates $f$ exactly as in amplitude modulation.

It's the variation in the intensity of $f$ caused by $g$ that we hear as the beat.

**Response to comment:**

Have a look at this image from [this article about amplitude modulation](https://www.electronicshub.org/modulation-and-different-types-of-modulation/):

[image: Amplitude modulation]

When the modulation is described as *slow* this means *slow compared to the carrier frequency*. That is, it means the frequency of the modulating wave $g$ must be a lot less than the frequency of the carrier wave $f$.

In your system the carrier signal is the function I've called $f(t)$ with a frequency $(\omega_1 + \omega_2)/2$. The modulating signal is the function I've called $g(t)$  with a frequency $(\omega_1 - \omega_2)/2$. Hopefully it's obvious that the frequency of $f$ has to be much higher than the frequency of $g$ because that gives a nice clear modulation. If the frequencies are too similar then when you multiply $f$ and $g$ you just get an unholy mess with no clear beat pattern.

If $\omega_1 \approx \omega_2$ the the average of the two frequencies is a high frequency and the difference is a small frequency.

Comment: +1. Sir, can you tell why Mr.French mentioned about **slow modulation**? And sir, one thing more, why is it important to have $\omega_1 \approx \omega_2$?

Comment: @user36790: I've edited my answer to respond to your cmment.